# VBO General Geometry

Tags: c++, opengl, haskell, abstract, vbo

I'm making a rendering engine in Haskell, and am optimising my code to use VBOs. I'd like to abstract the type of geometry a bit, as there are a decent amount, and would like to kind of stick it in one function, and a few parameters.

For example, if I have one set of geometry which is a list of pairs of vertices and normals i.e. `[(Vertex, Normal)]`. I set the stride to 6, in the descriptor, set the size for 3 for each and then the offset for the normals as 3.

Now, if I wanted to do just a list of vertices i.e. [Vertex], could I set the size of the stride to be 3, and size of the normal to be 0 but still set the pointers and everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [OpenGL documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) for `glVertexAttribPointer`:

> *size*
> Specifies the number of components per generic vertex attribute. Must     
> be 1, 2, 3, 4. Additionally, the symbolic constant `GL_BGRA` is accepted 
> by **glVertexAttribPointer**. The initial value is 4.

Hence, you cannot call a pointer to something whose type has size zero. In order to not use normals, you'd have to use a different VBO.

Comment: Why a different VBO? The buffer object is just memory which is totally under the user's control. There is nothing which prevents having several objects with different vertex formats in the same VBO.

Comment: Ok, cool. I know how much I can abstract out then. Thanks! Yeah, I'll use the same VBO. All the binding and stuff should be the same, just the offsets and stuff is different I think. Thanks, both of you!

Comment: @Gentatsu If I properly understand what you're trying to do, you shouldn't have a problem with the VBO storage. But you *will* have to skip the `glVertexAttribPointer()` call for the normals if you don't have them. And make sure that you don't enable the corresponding attribute.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I got from the answer. It's in quite a complex chain of code, so I didn't want to play around with it too much in case I lost where I was, and had to roll back again anyway. It's good to know where I stand, and do it in  a bit as opposed to dive straight in. Thanks!